# expand/collapse div in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to expend top div as following :

[image]

and i want to expand something like this :

[image]

the problem is , my all div shifting down, when i put height for div 2 , i want my 2nd div overlap on div.

my html like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/u6hy87vr/ ( this is responsive design so may be it doest look like as picture i attached here, please make jsfiddle wider)

i tried to put code like this to expand :

```
  $("#div").css("height","400px");
```

Comment: Did you know that the amount of effort people put into your questions has a direction correlation with the number of answers you accept

Comment: Yes, but i dont get answer, please suggest me what should i do, i really appreciated the people who help

Comment: I think what @LloydBanks is trying (diplomatically) to say is that you need to start accepting (and upvoting) some of the answers to your past questions...